# Join 3 Table Sum Group By MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter, what I want to sum(stock_in) and sum(stock_out) and group by id_barang:

Table Stock

| code | name | stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B01 | Book | 40 |

Table Stock IN

| code | name | stock in |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B01 | Book | 20 |
| B01 | Book | 10 |

Table Stock OUT

| code | name | stock out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B01 | Book | 5 |
| B01 | Book | 10 |

I want result:
Summary

| code | name | stock | stock in | stock out | last stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B01 | Book | 40 | 30 | 15 | 55 |

last stock = (stock + stock in) - stock out

I can join 3 table but the sum(stock_in) and sum(stock_out) like this:

| code | name | stock | stock in | stock out | last stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B01 | Book | 40 | 60 | 30 | 70 |

Comment: group and sum the tables before joining and there is no need for two tables at all

Comment: You might find it simpler to have a single transactions table

Comment: Hi @median: Have You got desired result? If not then please check my answer below if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach (using the fiddle thoughtfully provided by RahulBiswas) ...

```
SELECT s.code   
     , s.name
     , s.stock
     , SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 'in' THEN qty END) stock_in
     , SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 'out' THEN qty END) stock_out
     , s.stock+SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 'in' THEN qty END)-SUM(CASE WHEN direction = 'out' THEN qty END) balance
  FROM stock s
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT code
            , name
            , stock_in qty
            , 'in' direction
         FROM stock_in
        UNION ALL
       SELECT code
            , name
            , stock_out 
            , 'out' 
         FROM stock_out
    ) x
   ON x.code = s.code;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dc765/10

Answer (score 0):

As per your desired output INNER JOIN is used here. But If code (B01) is not exists in stock_in and Stock_out table then Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. COALESCE function is used in amount field to ignore NULL.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT s.code, s.name, s.stock, si.stock_in, so.stock_out
     , (s.stock + si.stock_in - so.stock_out) last_stock
FROM Stock s
INNER JOIN (SELECT code, MAX(name) name
                 , SUM(stock_in) stock_in
            FROM Stock_in
            GROUP BY code) si
        ON s.code = si.code
INNER JOIN (SELECT code, MAX(name) name
                 , SUM(stock_out) stock_out
            FROM Stock_out             
            GROUP BY code) so
            ON s.code = so.code;
```

Please check the result from url http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dc765/4

Please check the result where left join is used http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e97ef3/2